# Skip DOCTYPE in SAX parser

Tags: python, sax

I'm reading a XML File with SAX

But, I cant seem to figure out the way to make it skip the following line

```
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
```

I get the error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 280, in _parse
raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '../procesar rules/powrmart.dtd'
```

Does anyone know how to handle exceptions or skip this line with sax?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    fp = open("file_name","r")
    fp2 = open("file_name_temp","w+")
    for line in fp:
        if (line.find("DOCTYPE")<0):
            fp2.writelines(line)
    fp.close()
    fp2.close()
```